# Magento-2 Block rewrite not working

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

di.xml code of my module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
          <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" />
  </config>
```

Block file Configurable.php as below:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type;

class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
{   
    public function getAllowProducts()
    { 
        exit('test');
    }  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top of your `di.xml` file ?

Comment: Yes i have `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top

Comment: Did you try deleting the `var/generation` and `var/cache` folders ?

Comment: Yes already i have deleted many times, but no luck.

Comment: Is your `di.xml` file located under `etc/frontend` ?

Comment: No my di.xml file located at etc/di.xml . After your comment i have moved it to frontend and clear cache and var/generation but not working

Comment: How do you know it's not working ? Where are you calling that `getAllowProducts` method ? If it's in a template could you try seeing what's in `get_class($block);` ?

Comment: I am trying to show out of stock simple product option of configure product. Placed exit in function still frontend option dropdown remain same.

Comment: do you have register you module?Mean have you create register.php and composer.json for your module

Comment: Module is working fine also i have rewrite a model, it is also working. But this block is not working.